# Slow mongodb FindOneAndUpdate

Tags: mongodb, performance

I'm having trouble with the following findOneAndUpdate MongoDB query:

```
planSummary: IXSCAN { id: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 keysInserted:1 keysDeleted:1 numYields:0 reslen:3044791 

locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } 

storage:{} protocol:op_query 135ms

writeConcern: { w: 0, j: false }
```

As you can see it has execution time of +100 ms. The query part uses an index and takes less than 1ms (using 'Explain query'). So it's the write part that is slow.

The Mongo instance is the master of a 3 member replica set. Write concern is set to 0 and journaling is disabled.

What could be the cause of the slow write? Could it be the update of indices?

MongoDB version 4.0
Driver: Node.js native mongodb version 3.2

Edit: I think it might be the length of the result. After querying a document smaller in size, the execution time is halved.

Answer (score 0):

```
 reslen:3044791
```

This was the source of the bad performance. Reducing this by adding a projection option to only return a specific field improved the execution from ~90ms on average to ~7ms.